# VBA: Excel macro code correction

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a VBA code that can help me to click a button from a web page. I got the below VBA from one of the sites which works as expected.

```
Sub followWebsiteLink()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim Link As Object
Dim ElementCol As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "https://www.google.co.in"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Loading website…"
DoEvents
Loop

Set html = ie.document
Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each Link In ElementCol
If Link.innerHTML = "Google Pixel 2" _ 'Or u can use "Advertising"
Then
Link.Click
End If
Next Link

Set ie = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But if I replace it with the site name I want, it wont work.

**The changes I made are as follows **

```
ie.navigate "https://www.flipkart.com/"


For Each Link In ElementCol
If Link.innerHTML = "Log In" _
And Link.getElementsByClassName = "_2k0gmP" _
Then
Link.Click
End If
Next Link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, worked for me to click on `Log In`

#### Code

```
#If VBA7 Then
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
#Else
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If

Sub test()
Dim IE As Object
Dim htmlDoc As Object
Dim sURL As String

' CREATING OBJECT
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

sURL = "https://www.flipkart.com/"
' WEBPAGE NAVIGATION
With IE
.navigate (sURL)
.Visible = True
End With

WaitIE IE, 2000

' CLICK ON LOG IN
Set htmlDoc = IE.document
Set buttonclick = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("_2k0gmP")

buttonclick(7).Click
WaitIE IE, 5000

'IE.Quit
'Set IE = Nothing
End Sub

Sub WaitIE(IE As Object, Optional time As Long = 250)
'Code from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808000/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set
Dim i As Long
Do
    Sleep time
    Debug.Print CStr(i) & vbTab & "Ready: " & CStr(IE.readyState = 4) & _
                vbCrLf & vbTab & "Busy: " & CStr(IE.Busy)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until IE.readyState = 4 Or Not IE.Busy
End Sub
```

#### Edit

You can use this code to get the href:

```
For Each Element In buttonclick
Debug.Print Element.href
Next
```

Or to get the InnerText:

```
For Each Element In buttonclick
Debug.Print Element.innerText & " " & i
i = i + 1
Next
'Where i is the number of the item
```

Then you can use conditional such as:

```
For Each Element In buttonclick
If Element.href = "href_link" Then Element.Click
Next
```

OR

```
For Each Element In buttonclick
If Element.innerText = "Log In" Then Element.Click
Next
```

Comment: Thanks @ danieltakeshi, Please guide me how to mention the HREF as well to this code so that I wont land up in clicking some wrong link/button... Infact now this is taking me to a seprate page because ClassName ("_2k0gmP") was not a unique value, there are other tags having same value....

Comment: Yeah, buttonclick(0) is Sell on Flipkart, buttonclick(1) is Advertise, buttonclick(2) is Gift Card, [...], buttonclick(7) is Log In.

Comment: @ danieltakeshi `buttonclick(7).Click` works, I really looking forward to see how can we accomodate HREF "/account/login?ret=/" or HTML value "Sign In"  to this.... as a safer side.... in future any change in the web site may land up me in wrong button click :) I hope you understand me ! and this will be my last question.... And sorry if I am asking too much question.... If this is not possible please let me know :(

Comment: Thank you 
 
 
@ danieltakeshi