# VBA: Internet Explorer href link reference

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA and bumped into the below issue.
Using VBA I've been trying to activate a href link in Internet Explorer.

HTML Code (I want to refer to line 'title = Show archived file'):
Below html code states a table in which the href link is given.

```
    <td width="6%">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
    <tbody><tr>           
        <td><a href="URL_Replaced_Due_To_Security_Reasons" target="_blank">
        <img title="View as printed" align="middle" 
        src="/umadmin/style/common/images/pdf_2.png" border="0"></a></td>                

        <td><a href="URL_Replaced_Due_To_Security_Reasons"    
        target="_blank"><img title="Show archived file" align="middle"    
        src="/umadmin/style/common/images/pdf.gif" border="0"></a></td>             
    </tr>        
   </tbody></table>
   </td>
```

I was able to open this link by using the following VBA coding:

```
InternetExplorer.Navigate "URL_Replaced_Due_To_Security_Reasons"
```

Thought I would like to click on this without referring to the link directly, as this link is variable according to some prior input.

So what I've tried was the below, which unfortunately gives me an error:

```
MyBrowser.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")("Show archived file").Click
```

If somebody could take a look at this, I would be most grateful.

Kind regards,

Vik

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `MyBrowser.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very swift comment.
Thought this doesn't give a good solution either as it picks up the first "a" line and clicks on that one.

Comment: I'd need to see more of the HTML code to be able to navigate down to the appropriate tag line

Comment: I added some more code.
Note that everything before this code isn't related to the above question.
Are you able to provide feedback based on this?

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47333783/7690982) to click based on the href or innerText.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me to the solution@danieltakeshi!