# Interface is unknown error on executing the below vb script

Tags: vba, excel

i need to open IE and url. After that I need to click a link text with  tag.

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click() 

Dim IE As Object
Dim NewURL As String
Dim sURL As String
Dim strCountBody As String
Dim lStartPos As Long
Dim lEndPos As Long
Dim TextIWant As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set IE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")

sURL = "My Link" 'hidden for security reasons.
With IE
    .navigate sURL
    ' uncomment the line below if you want to watch the code execute, or for debugging
    .Visible = True
End With
' loop until the page finishes loading
Do While IE.Busy
Loop    

' click a text link on the page after that
Set ElementCol = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In ElementCol
    If link.innerHTML = "Link Text" Then
        NewURL = link.GetAttribute("href")
        Exit For
    End If
Next link
With IE
    .navigate NewURL
    ' uncomment the line below if you want to watch the code execute, or for debugging
    .Visible = True
End With
' loop until the page finishes loading
Do While IE.Busy
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Format your code with `code` markdown.  2. Which line errors out?

Comment: @Shai Rado I did the same formatting, but SO didn't want to save changes saying "the changes mostly affect the code". How did you do that?

Comment: @JohnyL just edited it

Comment: @ShaiRado Doesn't work for me for some reason :(

Comment: @PriyadharsiniStalin So, which line errors out?

Comment: Hi Johny, I am getting error in Do while IF busy step. I think I am answering in correct window. Please correct me If I am wrong

Comment: If you’re trying to navigate an intranet, try to replace ‘Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")’ with ‘Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorerMedium.Application")’ and dun the same code.

Comment: I am getting "ActiveX component can't create object" error :(

Comment: I normally use [This Function to wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808000/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set) and refer to [this example on how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47333783/7690982)

Comment: Now I am getting interface error in step : For Each a In IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")

Comment: i use code to click link:
LinkHref = "http:link"
For Each a In IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")
  If LCase(a.GetAttribute("href")) = LCase(LinkHref) Then
    a.Click
    Exit For  ''# to stop after the first hit
  End If
pls help

Comment: @PriyadharsiniStalin Can you provide the link?

Comment: <A href="http://syasds/hxx/test.html" target=_blank>DDD (XH) Test/QA/UAT Sys</A>
I have modified the https and inner text.